Can は function like など?
There is one sentence in the below page I am uncertain with:

成長カプセルはともかく記憶力プセルはほとんど完成までこぎつけたものが入っているし

Based on my understanding もの refers to 力プセル. In that case, I think は means など because 記憶力プセル is an example of 完成までこぎつけたもの. Is that right?


This は is a normal topic marker with a contrastive sense. 記憶カプセル is a category and もの refers to a specific type of it that's included in 37種混合カプセル. The contrast is with 成長カプセル, the specific type of which in 37種混合カプセル may not be completely tested.

は can’t function like など here, because “もの” seems to refer to the previously mentioned 記憶カプセル. However, some readers might think that もの indicates the existence of other types of untested 記憶カプセル or that 記憶カプセル contains ingredients that are almost fully tested.
Anyway, this sentence alone would be very difficult to understand.
